# facebook messenger greeting with more than 160 characters

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nLLy.jpg)For one of my chat bot I am trying to add greeting message in FB messenger and the allowed limit is 160 characters maximum. But when I check some public available bots like "TobyAir - Tigerair Australia" greeting message is more than 230 characters in mobile apps. How to do that as FB api do not provide any such option. Can some one advise on this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are seeing in TobyAir and other bots are not greeting messages but **instant replies**. As you mentioned, greetings are restricted to 160 characters but instant replies are limited to 250. The reason is probably that the scope of a greeting is a short introduction of the bot. While the instant reply is intended to provided features, common uses/commands or additional information.

Instant replies trigger when the user first chat to the bot, like saying "hello" for example. You can reduce your greeting text to a short introduction and wait for the user to interact with your bot to provide additional information.

Comment: @Francisco Ponce Gomez thanks for ur reply. Can ve a look on attached image? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nLLy.jpg) I dont think this is instant reply. This seems to me like a greeting message. Correct me if I were wrong.

Comment: Seems that they are using more characters than the limit indeed. This is something we don't have control over but Facebook. Maybe you could reach to their support team and ask them if there is a way to solve this problem. I don't know a way to overcome this problem besides what I suggested you on my previous answer.